# Asking for a retraction as a non-academic

Tags: publications, correspondence, retraction

I am a software developer and recently implemented an algorithm from a paper in an academic journal. I am convinced that the algorithm is fundamentally flawed, having spent several hours working with it as well as with the author's original source code. This paper has not been cited for its results, only its existence.

The authors, including the corresponding author, were undergraduates and appear to no longer be in academia. The exception is the first author who was and is tenured faculty.

What are my options for correcting the record? As far as I can see, I can:

- attempt to write a rebutting paper - but I do not have the time to do so, even if I could marshal my mind back into academic mode
- contact the first author - which seems courteous but perhaps not particularly fruitful
- contact the journal - but I can't find any obvious contact info

Are there any other options open to me? What is likely to be most productive?

Comment: Papers are generally retracted for academic misconduct of some sort, not simply for being false. Accordingly, contacting the journal is unlikely to produce any result. No journal will retract a paper just because you contact it and tell them that you are "convinced that the algorithm is fundamentally flawed" (and rightly so). How is the journal supposed to know whether you are right or the authors are right? On the other hand, the authors could decide to willingly retract it if you convince them that they are wrong.

Comment: Ignoring the implementation, if you believe the _algorithm_ to be incorrect, have you spotted the flaw, particularly if there’s an incorrect proof? Isolate the flaw or gap before contacting the authors.

Comment: When you ask "what is likely to be most productive", what is your goal?

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of bad papers out there....

Comment: "Several hours" does not sound like very much time. Leave it for a few weeks, then investigate it again as thoroughly as you can. Then if you are still convinced it is wrong, follow Ethan Bolker's advice.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil. I'm increasingly worried that retractions for being wrong are becoming more common.

Comment: Thanks all; first thoughts amid the holidays as follows. I'm surprised that retraction is only for misconduct, thought that it also included fundamental error. Would not expect journal to retract on its own accord but was hoping they might publish a letter to editor. Re. algorithm - there is no proof to correctness, only to time/space complexity - the described algorithm does have the time complexity claimed but produces an incorrect result; the author-provided implementation appears to produce the correct result but has major discpreancies (both in method and complexity) from the paper.

Answer (score 58):

I would start by contacting the corresponding author, probably with a cc to the first author faculty member.

Explain why you want to implement the algorithm, describe your attempt and the problems you encountered.

Keep your questions and concerns polite and factual - nothing about fatal flaws in the algorithm.

In principle, the authors should be pleased that their work has been noticed and want it to be corrected if it's wrong. Retraction should not be part of the discussion at this stage.

Comment: Exactly. For example, typos? Ask for clarification, first. :)

Comment: It may be wrong but fixable as well.

Comment: This is great advice.  I once did a derivation of an equation in a paper and I couldn't get it to work.  After contacting the authors, who had long since retired, I learned that it was the journal's error in typesetting (the paper was from 1978), and they had addressed this in their follow-on papers, which I didn't read as they weren't primarily what I was after.  10k+ citations on the paper with an error, and <100 on all of the papers that the same group wrote with the updates.

Comment: Good answer, but maybe include that after the discussion has failed many Journals have a "comment" type of (short) response to an published article.

Comment: Contacting the author is the correct course of action because of the culture of Academia; you don't go nuclear right out of the gate. Be gentle and cautious, because you may even be wrong yourself. It is also possible that there is a small typo, or something equally minor, which can be fixed. And then you have the added benefit of not only making a real contribution to science, but also making great connections. You burn bridges fast when you skip the proper channels, and miss out on a great opportunity to build relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts; do you suggest I leave it if I can't get in touch/don't hear back? At the end of the day, I assume there is merit to the academic record being correct, but at the same time, must be a realist as to how much effort is sensible.

Comment: @waiwai933 Whether you proceed on your own if you don't hear back depends on how important the problem is to you and how important you think it is to the world and how much time you want to invest. No need to decide until you've tried and failed to reach the authors. Let us know here what happens.

Answer (score 9):

If you are mainly interested in pointing out the flaw in the original article (or if you reached out to the author and/or journal but you are not satisfied with their response), there is also the option to post your analysis on [pubpeer.com](https://pubpeer.com), either with your name or anonymously.

Comments on PubPeer have led to high-profile investigations & retractions, see [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubPeer).

Comment: Pubpeer is the best choice here, as you are probably not interested in investing a lot of time into your comment, but would like to prevent others from wasting their time as you did. You do not need to have any scientific background. This option is fast and does not rely on the authors response to make it useful for other readers.

Answer (score 2):

The journal editors do not know if the code is correct and they do not know if you're right, but they have the opinion of usually three reviewers who considered the paper (and possibly the code) to be right.

What could change their minds would be another peer-reviewed paper proving that the code is wrong. On the other hand, once the other paper is published, the retraction would only be a minor detail as everyone could read themselves the proof that the paper is wrong.

In summary: The editors do not know, the authors and the reviewers claim it is correct and you are alone claiming it's wrong. It's unlikely the editors will do something about it.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph: I've successfully published several papers describing algorithms, including in good quality journals, and I'm 99% certain that none of the reviewers who have reviewed my papers and approved them would be able to answer the question "is the algorithm correct?", let alone "is the code a correct implementation of that algorithm?". That would be wayyyyy too much work and I wouldn't expect it from a reviewer.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend trying to publish a paper whose main message is "here is a proof that these authors' algorithm was completely wrong" without contacting these authors first. I think contacting the authors is, at least, a professional courtesy in this situation; they might be willing to cooperate in publishing a proof that their own algorithm was wrong, or better yet, publishing a new, fixed, algorithm. So you end up with a friend instead of an enemy.

Comment: Also. It would be much more significant if you could show exactly where the flaw lies, and demonstrate how to fix it. Failure to reproduce results, may simply mean you had an odd dataset that doesn't fit the case the solution was designed for,  or that your implementation was faulty, as well as the same having happened to the researchers; you need to be able to explain the difference, or at least try to characterize the ranges where it doesn't work after extensive testing. Remember that a paper us stating observations and proposing a model, not asserting a law of nature  has been proven.

Comment: Indeed, either the authors should write a corrigendum themselves, or your paper should provide more than just pointing out an error in the other paper.

Answer (score 2):

You would write your own paper reassessing the original one. Please respect others proceedings and never compete with authors - cooperate instead.

In addition, redefinition of "wrong" algorithm should start with reproducible experiment showing fundamental refutation: evaluation, metrics and corresponding stuff. The seed is to provide scientific problem but C++ developer confusion.

Unfortunately, nowadays some poor quality papers are mainly forced by laboratory sponsors which leads too low experienced students sciencfricking. Hence contacting the authors will not be the case (as for me).

Answer (score 2):

In fields such as economics, it is possible to submit a commentary paper. This type of paper undergoes peer review, and if deemed relevant by reviewers and the journal's editor, it may be published in an issue.

As some comments have suggested, if you identify an issue, it is essential to formally prove its inaccuracy by presenting a clear methodology.

In many cases, a paper is not retracted unless there is academic misconduct, such as falsifying data, etc. Also, there is no reason to retract a paper. This shows how different fields of science function.

Here is an example of a paper published in a reputable journal. Without delving into specific details, the paper's primary conclusion is the existence of an important fact, denoted as "A."

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0022-2879.2007.00002.x

Another author has written a commentary paper, disproving this result and scientifically demonstrating that the fact "A" does not exist:

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1538-4616.2008.00192.x

Notably, the original paper has not been retracted. If you are considering responding to this article, you have two options:

1. Contact the editor-in-chief or someone, possibly an associate editor, from the editorial board. Inquire whether they are interested in a commentary paper. However, be cautious, as this opportunity may be your only chance to publish such a paper. It's unlikely that another journal would be interested in publishing a commentary on a work that has already been published elsewhere.
2. Write a general paper on this topic and show that your results are better than the existing papers in the literature.